# Generate an RSA public / private key pair

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm looking for the simplest way to generate an `RSA` public / private key pair in `swift` I've been seeing a lot talk about how `iOS` doesn't support `OpenSSL`.

I simply need to generate the key pair and send the public key over to my server, the server will `encrypt` some data with the key and send it back over for my private key to `decrypt`. This is a one time transaction and I wont need the key anymore after that.

What is the simplest and lightest solution for this?

Comment: If the transfer is just between your client and your server, why not just use HTTPS?

Comment: @blobbfuesch we are using HTTPS but my employer is concerned that it is not enough security so we are trying to implement another level underneath the HTTPs.

Comment: If AES is not safe enough, RSA isn't either. When comparing the strength of keys, RSA-1024 is less secure than AES-128. (Source: [this answer from the information security sister forum](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/89973))

Comment: @blobbfuesch the plan is to use AES for later transactions but we are going to use RSA to send the cipher key from the server to the client. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: I would use HTTPS for the encryption with perfect forward secrecy with 4096 Bit RSA. Even if the server key gets stolen, only active sessions can get decrypted (encrypting the data with a public key from the client would not help here). all previous traffic is safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This Github repo - **[Heimdall](https://github.com/henrinormak/Heimdall)**, should help you with generating keys and encrypting your data.

### Example usage:

```
if let heimdall = Heimdall(tagPrefix: "com.example") {
    let testString = "This is a test string"
// Encryption/Decryption
if let encryptedString = heimdall.encrypt(testString) {
    println(encryptedString) // "cQzaQCQLhAWqkDyPoHnPrpsVh..."

    if let decryptedString = heimdall.decrypt(encryptedString) {
        println(decryptedString) // "This is a test string"
    }
}

// Signatures/Verification
if let signature = heimdall.sign(testString) {
    println(signature) // "fMVOFj6SQ7h+cZTEXZxkpgaDsMrki..."
    var verified = heimdall.verify(testString, signatureBase64: signature)
    println(verified) // True

    // If someone meddles with the message and the signature becomes invalid
    verified = heimdall.verify(testString + "injected false message",
                                signatureBase64: signature)
    println(verified) // False
}
```

### Encrypting data with own public key:

The **[swift-rsautils](https://github.com/btnguyen2k/swift-rsautils)** by [btnguyen2k](https://github.com/btnguyen2k) Utils should help you with encrypting your data with your own public key. Its really simple to use.

#### How to use:

First just drag and drop the `RSAUtils.swift` file to your project.

And thats it!

#### Encrypting basic string:

```
let PUBLIC_KEY = "MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAJh+/sdLdlVVcM5V5/j/RbwM8SL++Sc3dMqMK1nP73XYKhvO63bxPkWwaY0kwcUU40+QducwjueVOzcPFvHf+fECAwEAAQ=="

let sampleText:String = "WHATS UP"

let encrypted:NSData? = RSAUtils.encryptWithRSAPublicKey(sampleText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, pubkeyBase64: PUBLIC_KEY, keychainTag: "yourdomain.com")

let encryptedDataText = encrypted!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())

print(encryptedDataText)
```

**This prints:**

```
ML5S87dfDB6l1uHFcACm2IdkGHpDGPUaYoSNTO+83qcWYxTEddFeKhETIcqF5n67nRDL0lKi5XV9uEI7hGTyKA==
```

Comment: Ive seen this repo before but I dont see any example of generating the keys? Could you provide one?

Comment: Any idea if its possible to insert my own public key for encrypting use?

Comment: Probably not, because that would also be unsecure. Always generate a new key pair.

Comment: Can I ask why it would be insecure? My server sends over its public key and then I encrypt my data with it and send it back to the server to decrypt with its private key.

Comment: Lets say, you hardcode your private key, and then use your own public key that works with that key, then someone could get the private key with reverse engineering (decompiling). And also that keys dont change. If you generete new pair of keys everytime you launch your app, or everytime per install, then it would be very hard to get the keys stolen.

Comment: But the private key is stored on the server. They cant decompile that.

Comment: So you dont generate the keys, the server does ?  You just encrypt the message with the public key from the server? Ill update my answer today, stay put.

Answer (score 5):

This is the simplest way to generate a RSA key pair in Swift using `SecKeyGeneratePair`:

```
        var statusCode: OSStatus
        var publicKey: SecKey?
        var privateKey: SecKey?

        let publicKeyAttr: [NSObject: NSObject] = [kSecAttrIsPermanent:true, kSecAttrApplicationTag:"publicTag".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!]
        let privateKeyAttr: [NSObject: NSObject] = [kSecAttrIsPermanent:true, kSecAttrApplicationTag:"privateTag".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!]

        var keyPairAttr = [NSObject: NSObject]()
        keyPairAttr[kSecAttrKeyType] = kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA
        keyPairAttr[kSecAttrKeySizeInBits] = 512
        keyPairAttr[kSecPublicKeyAttrs] = publicKeyAttr
        keyPairAttr[kSecPrivateKeyAttrs] = privateKeyAttr

        statusCode = SecKeyGeneratePair(keyPairAttr, &publicKey, &privateKey)

        if statusCode == noErr && publicKey != nil && privateKey != nil {
            printMessage = "Key pair generated OK"
            print("Public Key: \(publicKey!)")
            print("Private Key: \(privateKey!)")
        } else {
            printMessage = "Error generating key pair: \(statusCode)"
        }
```

Comment: How to covert the public and private key to string ?

Comment: Note that kSecAttrKeySizeInBits = 512 is no longer secure. See https://arstechnica.com/security/2015/10/breaking-512-bit-rsa-with-amazon-ec2-is-a-cinch-so-why-all-the-weak-keys/ for example.

Comment: It seems like Apple is recommending to use SecKeyCreateRandomKey in lieu of SecKeyGeneratePair which is a "legacy iOS key operation". https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys?language=objc