# How can I generate an RSA key pair in Swift on Linux?

Tags: swift, linux, rsa, vapor

I know that when using Swift on iOS or macOS you can use SecKeyGeneratePair, but the Security library is unavailable on Linux. Short of falling back on Process to use the the OpenSSL CLI interface, is there any way to generate an RSA key pair in Swift.

FYI, I'm using Vapor 3 to build a web API.

Comment: One option would be to review the GitHub Swift repositories found with the [search string 'openssl language:swift'](https://github.com/search?q=openssl+language%3Aswift). The search returns several examples which programmatically use the OpenSSL C library header files from Swift on Linux.

Comment: I almost downvoted and moved to close on [Generate an RSA public / private key pair](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33021946/608639). But I see I was mistaken. *＋1* for asking an original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is many months later, but I thought I would at least update for any others. While I looked into Andrei's suggestion above to use Themis, in the end it really was simplest to simply use Process that I was avoiding originally.

I had to call some local scripts anyway, so I wrote a dead simple Shell class that wrapped Swift's Process. It's not multithreaded, so it's not great for performance. But it works for what I need. I just called OpenSSL's CLI and grabbed the output.

Shell Gist: https://gist.github.com/mattmaddux/9979ec992c2b9744b669bd1728c28c19

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cross-platform library [Themis](https://github.com/cossacklabs/themis) (Apache 2) + example [Swift wrappers](https://github.com/cossacklabs/SwiftThemis). The nice thing is that you can use the same API regardless of programming language or location (back/front).

You can generate both RSA & EC keys.
Tested on Vapor + Ubuntu 16.04